# iOS 10 Camera view showing API_Cancel_Title instead of Cancel

Tags: ios, camera, xcode8, ios10

I am working on an app using iOS 10 and using camera for taking pictures. When camera view opens, instead of cancel button there is a title "API_CANCEL_TITLE". And when I capture the pic the whole title is seeing, I want that instead of this long title it will be look "Cancel". I have used app localization. I searched few links but could not find the solution.

**Here is the screen shot:**

[image]

This is happening only in iOS 10, in iOS 9 it will working correctly
here is the code:

```
- (IBAction)takePicturePressed:(UIButton *)sender
{

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Please suggest...

Comment: Add the code you have used to show the camera.

Comment: Have you implemented 'imagePickerControllerDidCancel' this method? and what is the Localization native development region?

Comment: Yes, I have implemented all the required delegate methods for it

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've approached the same problem using [BundleLocalization](https://github.com/cmaftuleac/BundleLocalization)
and I've traced `UIImagePickerController` keys, that it gets from a bundle.

Turns out, it uses 4 "tables" (in NSBundle nomenclature):

- `CameraUI` (for camera)
- `PhotoLibraryServices` (for PhotoLibrary)
- `PhotoLibrary` (for PhotoLibrary)
- `PhotosUI` (for PhotoLibrary)

In my case, all I had to do, to localize `UIImagePickerController` interface, it was create in the project a couple of `.strings` files and localize them.

Below content of mentioned files with keys I've seen (with standard english values), they are pretty self explaining

**CameraUI.strings**

```
"PHOTO" = "PHOTO";
"AEAF_LOCK_TEXT" = "AE/AF LOCK";
"API_CANCEL_TITLE" = "Cancel";
"HDR_AUTO" = "Auto";
"HDR_ON" = "On";
"HDR_OFF" = "Off";
"TIMER_OFF_TEXT" = "Off";
"USE_PHOTO" = "Use Photo";
```

**PhotoLibraryServices.strings**

```
"PHOTOS" = "Photos";
"CAMERA_ROLL" = "Camera roll";
"ALL_SCREENSHOTS" = "Screenshots";
```

**PhotoLibrary.strings**

```
"CANCEL" = "Cancel";
"RETAKE" = "Retake";
"STREAM_SHARED_BY_ME_SUBTITLE" = "From You";
"STREAM_SHARED_BY_SUBTITLE" = "From %@";
"ALBUM_IMAGE_COUNT_FORMAT" = "%@ Photos";
"ALBUM_VIDEO_COUNT_FORMAT" = "%@ Videos";
"1_ALBUM_PHOTO" = "1 Photo";
"1_ALBUM_VIDEO" = "1 Video";
"ALBUM_TWO_TYPES_LABEL_COMMAS" = "%@, %@";
```

**PhotosUI.strings**

```
"ALL_PHOTOS_IN_LIBRARY" = "Moments";
"PXUserCollectionsSectionTitle" = "My Albums";
"FULL_PHOTOS_GRID_ZOOM_LEVEL_TITLE" = "Moments";
"NO_PHOTOS_OR_VIDEOS" = "No Photos or Videos";
"EMPTY_ALBUM_LIST_MESSAGE_iPhone" = "You can take photos and videos using camera, or sync photos and videos onto your iPhone using iTunes";
```

Comment: I had the same problem with you when I'm calling `UIImagePickerController` from UIWebView. I tried to create the CameraUI.strings file but nothing change. Can you show me more details about your answer? And I'm noticed that if I using safari to call `UIImagePickerController` this problem doesn't occurs. That so weird.

Comment: For me it works because I'm using  [BundleLocalization](https://github.com/cmaftuleac/BundleLocalization). It _swizzles_ `[NSBundle  localizedStringForKey:value:table:]`, so every access to any bundle route through your bundle of choice (default `[NSBundle mainBundle]`) and Camera and other things will use your localized file `CameraUI.strings`.

Comment: To use [BundleLocalization] is enough to compile it with your project. To change the localization language use `[BundleLocalization.sharedInstance setLanguage:lang]` where `lang` is string language identifier, by ex. for polish lang = "pl-PL", english "en", "en-US", for `base` localization lang = nil

Comment: It's worked for me. Thank you so much. 
Another question, I'm using iphone 7+ and in CameraUI had zoom button, but I don't know full title of it. Do you know what is the full title of this button or somewhere I can find the answer? Thanks

Comment: In `BundleLocalization` set a breakpoint in a method `[customLocaLizedStringForKey:value:table]` so You will be able to see all string keys (and will be a lot o them)

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, Thank you @shc

Comment: i need ask what about "Retake" in Camera UI
what is key it?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: I've just added few more "camera strings". In particular "Retake" localized string is located in `PhotoLibrary.strings` ("RETAKE" key)

Answer (score 5):

On this Extension of Bundle You need to check for the CameraUI in tableName.
Use that change the value for the key of "Api_Cancel_title" to "Cancel" 
Using your own Localized value where you used to declare a your own value

for example

English "API_CANCEL_TITLE" = "Cancel";

Hindi "API_CANCEL_TITLE" = "रद्द करना";

French "API_CANCEL_TITLE" = "Annuler";

```
// MARK: - Bundle Extension

extension Bundle {

    @objc func specialLocalizedStringForKey(_ key: String, value: String?, table tableName: String?) -> String {
        let currentLanguage = CSLanguage.currentAppleLanguage()
        var bundle = Bundle.main
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: currentLanguage, ofType: "lproj") {
            bundle = Bundle.init(path: path)!
        } else {
            let basePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Base", ofType: "lproj")
            bundle = Bundle.init(path: basePath!)!
        }
        if let name = tableName, name == "CameraUI"{
         let values = NSLocalizedString(key, comment: name)

         return values
        }
        if let name = tableName, name == "PhotoLibrary"{
         let values = NSLocalizedString(key, comment: name)

         return values
        }
        if let name = tableName, name == "PhotoLibraryServices"{
         let values = NSLocalizedString(key, comment: name)

         return values
        }
        if let name = tableName, name == "PhotosUI"
        {
         let values = NSLocalizedString(key, comment: name)

         return values
        }
        return bundle.specialLocalizedStringForKey(key, value: value, table: tableName)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have an approach, I know it will be not a perfect solution however until get a perfect one, we can use this:

Use an custom camera view. Manage it with condition if device version is 10 or greater than 10 then execute custom camera view settings else use the default camera view.

By using custom view, the API_Cancel_Title button hides and rest of the functionality works well. 
Here is the link that I used for a reference: [Removing the cancel button from Custom camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32564813/removing-the-cancel-button-from-custom-camera)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are not using Localization in your application, if you are using it, then properly configure all of your string files.

Search in your string file for `API_CANCEL_TITLE` and then set it to `Cancel`.

As the `Cancel` button of `UIImagePickerController` will change as per the localization.

Comment: I update the question, as this happening only in iOS 10, in 9 working correctly...

Comment: Have you searched for `API_CANCEL_TITLE` in your project ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue come when you replace localizedString function in Bundle class by another function that you create, that will prevent the system some time to get the reight localization values.

and some developers replace this function when they want to change the language of the app and show the changes immediately without closing the app, so find another way and try to not replace this function