# UIImagePickerController change bottom bar button title during image edit mode in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

[image]

> I want to change the UIImagePickerController bottom bar buttons during
>   image editing mode in swift 3, Xcode 8.2.1.
>   Currently buttons are showing like as i mentioned in picture.

```
class MyController:UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageV: RoundedImageView!

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.imagePicker.delegate = self
    }

    //MARK:- Action
    @IBAction func libraryButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        self.imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func cameraButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        self.imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // MARK: - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate Methods

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            self.imageV.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            self.imageV.image = pickedImage
        }

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

> Please suggest me..

Comment: The title "CHOOSE_PHOTO_BUTTON" looks like a localization key. Try global search this keyword in project, perhaps it's defined somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not using Localization in your application, if you are using it, then properly configure all of your string files.

Have a look at this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42008789/2898708

I added **PhotoLibrary.strings** and in it I added following strings

```
"CANCEL" = "Cancel";
/* Title of button to set contact photo */
"SET_PHOTO_BUTTON" = "Set Photo";

"CHOOSE_PHOTO_BUTTON" = "Choose";

"USE_PHOTO_BUTTON" = "Use Photo";
```