# Getting API_CANCEL_TITLE instead of cancel when opening camera using imagePicker

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

[Cancel button image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9VhN.jpg)

As shown in the attached image, I'm getting this cancel button title when I open the camera using ImagePicker as follow:

```
 let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
 imagePicker.delegate = self
 imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
 imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
 self?.parentViewController?.present(imagePicker, animated: true)
```

Comment: check this one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/42008789/5501817

Comment: I checked it, wasn't helpful

Comment: Are you using any string file?

Comment: yes, app contains localization, both arabic and English, but it don't include any API_CANCEL_TITLE

Comment: maybe try adding one?

Comment: I did, nothing changed, still applies API_CANCEL_TITLE

Comment: @Ali have u got a solution? I have the same issue.

Comment: nope, didn't find a solution

Comment: I have the same issue? @Ali you got any solution?